# Entity Framework 6: ToString() comparison of primary keys

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-6.1

Typically, one could retrieve a record from a primary key value using the following query (or we could use `Find()`, depending on the circumstances):

```
using (var context = new SomeContext())
{
    entity = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

**What is the impact of performing the same query, but with ToString()'ing the primary key values?**

Like so:

```
using (var context = new SomeContext())
{
    entity = context.Users
                    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id.ToString() == id.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why stop there? Why not call `.ToString()` a few more times, and append `""` for good measure? On a more serious note, you should be able to trace the SQL that gets generated without any issue, and see for yourself if there's a difference. Also, whether there's a difference may depend on the type of `Id`.

Comment: Yes, why ask here while you can do a simple benchmark? We can't even answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that if you have like a table of 1 million elements your query can take extra 1 second to execute. Literally same as double of

```
convert(nvarchar(36), Id)
```

+value compare. You can imagine short circuited char compare x36 times.